# Emulate Azure web app like slots supporting "swap" for on premise IIS10

Tags: iis

In azure you can have slots that you can deploy your web app to.
For example you can have Production and Staging slots.
You can deploy to Staging then test if everything is OK and if so swap Staging with Production slot. 
I believe that behind the scenes those slots are just 2 sites in IIS. 
My idea is to just swap bindings and rename the websites so the Staging slot/website will get http://prod-superapp.com binding and the Production slot/website will get http://stg-superapp.com binding then rename Production website to Staging and Staging to production.
The last step is needed so that when we deploy the next time we deploy to the Staging slot again.

Can you think of anything better than this? Do you find any problems with that approach that I am currently not aware of? I know that there can't be two site with the same binding running at the same time so that scheme will have some downtime while the whole process completes.

Comment: Have you solved this eventually? Having the same need and would expect that it should be in TOP 10 features of IIS...

Comment: I'm currently looking into using the Application Request Routing module in IIS to route to the 2 different sites and just change the config in ARR instead of rebinding the sites - I think this should pretty much eliminate the downtime from what I have read